# Application is waiting on splwow64.exe

Tags: windows, printing, spooler

I am currently trying to debug an 3rd party app crash. When the program crashes, I can see it in the resource monitor within Windows. When I click on "Analyze Wait Chain" I see the following.

"Thread ID: XXXX is waiting on a process (PID: XXXX) splwow64.exe"

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I'm fairly new to debugging so any threads or tips will be most appreciated! I unfortunately do not have the source code either.

Comment: Printer related?

Comment: This crash happens only with a certain mode of the application. I can use other modes and it works correctly. I can also just print to the printer from notepad and it works as well.

Comment: Also, if I look to see what splwow64 is doing in process monitor it says it's running. I've also tried to see if splwow64 is waiting for something else and it's not returning anything in the wait chain.